# jquery routine for the submit is not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html file with the contents as shown in below, I want to POST the data to some webpage, when the submit button is clicked. But, I am not seeing any action in the jquery side. Can someone enlighten me, on whats wrong with it?

```
  <HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("#emailSubmit).click(function(){

    $.post("mytest.asp",
    {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
</script>


<STYLE>
.buttonholder{border:0px solid gray;height:30px;width:200px;position:relative;color:gray;margin:10px}
.holder{border:2px solid gray;height:30px;width:200px;position:relative;color:gray;margin:10px}
div.holder:hover{border:2px solid #33b5e5}
.holder input[type=text]{height:28px;border:0;width:95%;font-weight:700;outline:none;color:gray;font-size:18px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px}
.holder input[type=text]:focus{color:#000}
.holder input[type=text]:focus[required=required]{background-color:#f1d1d1}
.holder input[type=email]{height:28px;border:0;width:95%;font-weight:700;outline:none;color:gray;font-size:18px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px}
.holder input[type=email]:focus{color:#000}
.holder input[type=email]:focus[required=required]{background-color:#f1d1d1}
.holder .mask-left{position:absolute;top:-2px;left:-2px;width:2px;height:80%;background-color:#fff}
.holder .mask-right{position:absolute;top:-2px;right:-2px;width:2px;height:80%;background-color:#fff}
.holder .mask-top{position:absolute;top:-2px;left:0;width:100%;height:2px;background-color:#fff}
</STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<form id="ccSelectForm">
<img src="./gettrixwhite.png"  alt="My logo" align="middle" >
<div class="holder">
    <input type="text" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="First Name *" required="required" />
    <div class="mask-left"></div>
    <div class="mask-right"></div>
    <div class="mask-top"></div>
</div>
<div class="holder">
    <input type="text" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Last Name *" required="required" />
    <div class="mask-left"></div>
    <div class="mask-right"></div>
    <div class="mask-top"></div>
</div>
<div class="holder">
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail"   placeholder="Email *" required="required" />
    <div class="mask-left"></div>
    <div class="mask-right"></div>
    <div class="mask-top"></div>
</div>
<div class="buttonholder">
  <button type="button" id="emailSubmit"   class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click here to sign up">Sign me up. &raquo;</button>
  </div>

</form>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: I have not checked the code yet but you miss double quote " here `("#emailSubmit).click(function(){` at the end of email Submit, try see if that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger the `click` event after the dom is ready.

```
    $(function() {
    $('#emailSubmit').click(function(){
        $.post("mytest.asp",
        {
            name: "Donald Duck",
            city: "Duckburg"
        },
        function(data){
            // make sure you are returing something. 
            alert("Data: " + data);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error:

```
$("#emailSubmit) //missing quotes at end
```

Also you need to wrap into dom ready:

```
$(function() {
  // your code here
});
```